# Mapping IEnumerable to class with one list as a property - using AutoMapper

Tags: c#, mapping, automapper

I am receiving an IEnumerable<Class1> from a third party api.

I would like to map it using Automapper to the following class:

```
public class WrapperClass
{
    public List<Class2> Items { get; set; }
}
```

So essentially I am thinking I need two mappings:

```
IEnumerable<Class1> ----> WrapperClass
_______

Class1 ----> Class2
```

How would I approach this in **Automapper**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you must first create mappings for map Class1 to Class2 like:

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<Class1, Class2>().ForMember(x => x.A, y => y.MapFrom(z => z.B));
```

Then create mapping for map collection on class like:

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<IEnumerable<Class1>, WrapperClass>().ForMember(x => x.Items, y => y.MapFrom(z => z));
```

Finally you can use it like:

```
var wrapperClass = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Class1>, WrapperClass>(/* list */);
```

Below three class used for this example:

```
public class WrapperClass
{
    public List<Class2> Items { get; set; }
}

public class Class2 {
    public int A { get; set; }
}

public class Class1
{
    public int B { get; set; }
}
```